# Marketing Cloud SQL - Invalid Column name "Opt"

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, error-messages

I receive the following error message for my SQL statement and I cannot find the error:
"An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'Opt'

This was a quite similar problem, however it did not help me to solve my problem.
[Marketing Cloud SQL - Invalid Column Name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290258/marketing-cloud-sql-invalid-column-name/326289?noredirect=1#comment483239_326289)

Does anyone has a solution for me. What did I do wrong?
The SQL statement is:

```
I.PlayerID, M.Opt-In_Mail, S.Opt-in_SMS
from
ContactableUsers_MultiBetslip_20201110 as I
inner join 
MasterData_Email as M on I.PlayerID = M.ID
inner join 
MasterData_SMS as S on I.PlayerID = S.ID
```

Comment: Please add the data extension structure in your question. Also, can't see the select in your query, must be a typo :)

Comment: Oh yes, before the first row the select missing. But that was definitely there.
The structure of the date extension that shall be filled is:

PlayerID - Opt-In_Mail - Opt-in_SMS

The Data Extensions from which the data shall be taken have these information and a lot more.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that SQL has trouble with the - in a field name.
Just make sure it understands it by wrapping the fieldname in brackets. In general, just don't use "-" in fieldnames and it won't happen again :)

this works:

```
S.[Opt-in_SMS]
```

Not saying that Query Studio is to be trusted verbatim, but it can help sometimes. Query studio's highlighter shows this behavior, you see it interprets everything following the "-" as something other than the fieldname. This query fails like yours.

[image]

fixed (and this query works):

[image]

Comment: It worked out :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: To add to Jonas' answer, if you need to split a word use an underscore '_' (eg: opt_in). You won't have any issues that way.